# the relationship(s) between A and B of multiple samples

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I would like to know which of the following is best to describe the diagram;

> 1. This diagram shows the relationship between current and voltage of
>      two samples.
> 2. This diagram shows the relationships between current and
>          voltage of two samples.

In short, my question is that the word "relationship" should be in a plural form?

[image]

Comment: Two samples; two **relationships**.

Comment: How about "This diagram shows the relationship between current and voltage of each of two samples". I added "each".

Comment: Yes, that's fine too.

Comment: Your graph is misleading. I only see one set of samples. A legend would normally be added so the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this one's iffy. Presumably there is only one "true" relationship between current and voltage, A=V/R. However many experiments you perform, however many samples you have, they SHOULD all show the same relationship. Of course in real life there will be experimental error and intrusion of other factors: empirical data is rarely 100% clean.

Comment: So to summarize, one relationship.  Refer to it in the singular.